# I could not signup using the direct method

Tags: bug, sign-up

I was not able to sign-up without using my Google account. I tried signing up directly using Internet Explorer 10 and the screen locked. I tried it using Chrome and it worked, but I never received a confirmation Email. I tried it twice this way using Chrome.

I could not find the Email in SPAM box so it seems the Email is not going out. I did sign up OK with my Google account, but wanted to let you know the direct sign-up which I would have preferred does not work.